# Slow response with WSO2 enterprise integration using message broker

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I use WSO2 EI 6.1.0 to this scenario:

1. A client(SOAPUI project) send a message to a proxy service(PS_A) inside EI.
2. The proxy service(PS_A) store the message in a Queue, define in embebed MB, with a response queue defined with `transport.jms.ReplyDestination`.
3. Another proxy(PS_B) get the message from the queue and send a message to a backend service, with the backend response, create a new message and send it as a response.
4. The response arrive to the client.

My problem it´s that the response time is very slow, about 9s with the embebed MB. If I use a external broker like ActiveMQ, the response time it´s about 400ms or less.

Answer (score 0):

The WSO2 MB has various settings / parameters that you can configure such in axis2.xml file or inside the proxies  (Producer - PS-A) and (Consumer - PS-B).
Therefore, to make the execution process faster, you can use the caching level, such as for producer and consumer.

Ps_A: < parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">producer< /parameter >
Ps_B: < parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">consumer< /parameter>

Hope this helps